# Show that $(n!)^{(n-1)!}$ divides $(n!)!$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, prime-factorization

> Show that $(n!)^{(n-1)!}$ divides $(n!)!$

I found this question in a text he was reading about *BREAKDOWN OF PRIME FACTORS IN FACT*, I decided many years, have posted some here to help, but this ... Did not come out at all, in fact I could not leave the place, and looked reolhei theorems that shows me the text, but could not solve, need help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\displaystyle\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)!}{\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^na_i!}
&=\frac{\displaystyle\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i\right)!}{\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i!}
\frac{\displaystyle\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)!}{\displaystyle\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i\right)!\ a_n!}\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i\right)!}{\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i!}
\binom{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^na_i}{a_n}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^n\binom{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^ka_i}{a_k}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the fraction on the left of $(1)$ is a product of binomial coefficients.

We can write
$$
n!=n(n-1)!=\sum_{i=1}^{(n-1)!}n\tag{2}
$$
Using $(2)$ and then $(1)$
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(n!)!}{n!^{(n-1)!}}
&=\frac{\displaystyle\left(\sum_{i=1}^{(n-1)!}n\right)!}{\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{(n-1)!}n!}\\[4pt]
&=\prod_{k=1}^{(n-1)!}\binom{kn}{n}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Since the right hand side of $(3)$ is a product of binomial coefficients, the left hand side is an integer.

---

**Example**

The numbers get huge very quickly, but with $n=4$,
$$
\frac{(4!)!}{4!^{3!}}=\frac{24!}{24^6}=3,246,670,537,110,000
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^{3!}\binom{4k}{4}
&=\binom{24}{4}\binom{20}{4}\binom{16}{4}\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4}\\[4pt]
&=3,246,670,537,110,000
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The statement that you made, is one that I draw attention and make me like it even more math, particularly, found it very beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: Nice solution.......marcelolpjunior..

Answer (score 5):

[Three years later update]
Addressing @Patrick’s comment, I should have said

Suppose you have $(n-1)!$ identical sets of $n$ balls. The balls in each set are numbered 1 through $n$. How many ...

[My original backwards answer follows.]

Suppose you have $n$ identical sets of $(n-1)!$ balls. The balls in each set are numbered 1 through $(n-1)!$. How many ways are there to arrange these $n!$ balls in a row? There are $\frac{(n!)!}{(n!)^{(n-1)!}}$ ways.

Comment: Doesn't this argument actually show that $\frac{(n!)!}{\bf{n}^{(n-1)!}}$ is an integer? Since there are $\bf n$ copies of each numbered ball and not $n!$?

Comment: This is essentially the combinatorial explanation of the product in my answer. The number of ways to place the balls marked $(n-1)!$ is $\binom{n(n-1)!}{n}$. After placing them, there are $\binom{n((n-1)!-1)}{n}$ ways of placing the balls marked $(n-1)!-1$, then $\binom{n((n-1)!-2)}{n}$ of placing the balls marked $(n-1)!-2$, and so on... (+1)

Comment: @Patrick: this is a standard multinomial coefficient:
$$
\frac{(n!)!}{n!^{(n-1)!}}=\frac{(\overbrace{n+n+n+\dots+n}^{(n-1)!\text{ terms}})!}{\underbrace{n!\,n!\,n!\dots n!}_{(n-1)!\text{ terms}}}
$$

Comment: Duh, of course!

Comment: @Steve Kass I enjoyed your response and your last comment, a certain theorem that I have here in my text fits perfectly, thanks for the reply. :)

Comment: @marcelolpjunior: to which of Steve's comments and to which theorem do you refer?

Comment: @robjohn If $a_1,...,a_m\in\mathbb{N}$ then $$\frac{(a_1+...+a_m)!}{a_1!\cdot\cdot\cdot a_m!}\in\mathbb{N}$$

Comment: @marcelolpjunior: are you talking about my comment?

Comment: @robjohn Yes, sorry, actually your comment ... My lack of attention ...
Your comment made ​​me enchergar the answer .... Thank you ....

Sorry, Sorry, Sorry, Sorry...

Comment: @marcelolpjunior: Ah, okay. [That comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575941/show-that-nn-1-divides-n/576152#comment1218436_576226) is simply a particular case of $(1)$ from [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/576152). Writing it in this particular case, without the summation notation, made it easier to explain what was going on.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as showing that [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) or [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\displaystyle{n\choose k}=C_n^k=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{n-j}{1+j}$ are always natural, for all values of *n* and *k*. It all depends on proving that the product of any *k* consecutive numbers is always divisible through the product of the first *k* consecutive numbers, $1$ through *k*. This is obvious, since, in each sequence of $2$ consecutive numbers, exactly one is even, and one odd; in each sequence of three consecutive numbers, exactly one is ternary, while the other two aren't; in each sequence of four consecutive numbers, exactly one is quaternary, while the rest aren't; etc. Our product, $(n!)!=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot n!$, can be broken up into $\displaystyle\frac{n!}n=(n-1)!$ sequences of *n* consecutive terms, each such sub-product being divisible through *n*!, for the reasons explained above. In other words, the whole product is divisible through $(n!)^{(n-1)!}$. QED.