# How to show $(mn)!$ is divisible by $(m!)^n$?

Tags: permutations, divisibility

How to show $(mn)!$ divides $(m!)^n$, $m$ and $n$ is integers?

Comment: It is wrong: Take $m=n=2$, $(mn)!=4!=24$, $(m!)^n=2!^2=4$.

Comment: It's wrong. Take a prime of the order of $mn$ (well, larger than $m$ is enough). It's in the prime decomposition of $(mn)!$ but certainly not in that of $(m!)^n$, if $n>1$ and $m>1$.

Comment: This might be backwards. If $n>m$ and $n$ is a prime, then it will be false.

Answer (score 3):

I presume you mean $(m!)^n$ divides $(mn)!$?

This is a consequence of the following fact:

If $\sum a_k = M$, then $\prod (a_k!)$ divides $M!$

Their ratio is just the multinomial coefficient, and multiple proofs can be given (search this site). A simple proof is to use induction, with the binomial coefficient as the base case.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you mean $m!^n$ divides $(mn)!$, in [equation $(1)$ of this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/576152), it is shown that
$$
\frac{\displaystyle\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)!}{\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^na_i!}
=\prod_{k=1}^n\binom{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^ka_i}{a_k}
$$
If we set all the $a_i$'s to $m$, we get
$$
\frac{(mn)!}{m!^n}=\prod_{k=1}^n\binom{km}{m}
$$
which gives your result.

Answer (score 1):

Factorials have a nice property that you can compute the exponent of any prime in their prime decomposition. The way this is done is nicely explained by [Legendre's theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/LegendresTheorem.shtml). Using it also solves this problem.

In this case the power of some prime $p$ in the decomposition of $(mn)!$ is

$ \sum_{k=1} \lfloor \frac{mn}{p^k} \rfloor$

and in the case of $(m!)^n$ we get

$ \sum_{k=1} n\lfloor \frac{m}{p^k} \rfloor$

Since $a \lfloor \frac{b}{c} \rfloor \leq \lfloor \frac{ab}{c} \rfloor$ (for all positive integers $a,b,c$) every term of the latter sum is less than or equal to that of the previous one hence establishing the (corrected) statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as showing that [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) or [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\displaystyle{n\choose k}=C_n^k=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{n-j}{1+j}$ are always natural, for all values of *n* and *k*. It all depends on proving that the product of any *k* consecutive numbers is always divisible through the product of the first *k* consecutive numbers, $1$ through *k*. This is obvious, since, in each sequence of $2$ consecutive numbers, exactly one is even, and one odd; in each sequence of three consecutive numbers, exactly one is ternary, while the other two aren't; in each sequence of four consecutive numbers, exactly one is quaternary, while the rest aren't; etc. Our product, $(mn)!$, can be broken up into *n* sequences of *m* consecutive terms, each such sub-product being divisible through *m*!, for the reasons explained above. In other words, the whole product is divisible through $(m!)^n$. QED.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $S_m \wr S_n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{mn}$.

Comment: What does $\wr$ mean, please?  I don't think I've ever seen that symbol before.

Comment: It denotes the wreath product between two groups.